.NET MAUI Blazor Virtualize Component - UI Instability with Shrinking and Jumping Issues
I am working on a .NET MAUI Blazor app and using the Virtualize component to display a grid and list view. I am encountering issues where the UI becomes unstable, shrinking, and jumping, especially when setting the OverscanCount. If I set it to less than 250, the UI shrinks; if I set it higher, the UI doesn't shrink but takes more time to load items.<Virtualize ItemsProvider="@LoadItems" Context="product" OverscanCount="75" ItemSize="300">
What could be causing this instability, and how can I stabilize the UI to prevent the shrinking and jumping issues?

Did this problem appear on all the platforms?

I checked windows and Android facing same issue - here code




Please wait.



Lock the size of your html container so it can calculate the scrolling correctly.
